# conflict between “.dir-locals.el” and “.dir-locals-2.el”?

Tags: directory-local-variables

Say there're 3 files:

```
/tmp/
 |
 |__ LICENSE
 |
 |__ .dir-locals.el    # Make LICENSE read-only
 |
 |__ .dir-locals-2.el  # Do nothing
```

```lisp
;;; /tmp/.dir-locals.el
((nil . ((eval . (when (string-match-p "\\`LICENSE\\(?:\\.[[:alpha:]]+\\)?\\'"
                                       (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)))
                   (setq-local buffer-read-only t)))))
 (nil . ()))  ; ... (1)
```

```lisp
;;; /tmp/.dir-locals-2.el
((nil . ()))  ; ... (2)
```

Yet Emacs still visits `/tmp/LICENSE` with write-permission.
IOW, the form `(eval . (when ...))` is ignored.

Why is it ignored?

---

I've found that these 2 combinations of `_dir-locals`s work fine:

- remove the 1st `(nil . ())`:

  ```lisp
  ;;; /tmp/.dir-locals.el
  ((nil . ((eval . (when (string-match-p "\\`LICENSE\\(?:\\.[[:alpha:]]+\\)?\\'"
                                     (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)))
                 (setq-local buffer-read-only t)))))
   ;; (nil . ())  ; ... (1)
   )
  ```

  ```lisp
  ;;; /tmp/.dir-locals-2.el
  ((nil . ()))  ; ... (2)
  ```
- remove the 2nd `(nil . ())`:

  ```lisp
  ;;; /tmp/.dir-locals.el
  ((nil . ((eval . (when (string-match-p "\\`LICENSE\\(?:\\.[[:alpha:]]+\\)?\\'"
                                     (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)))
                 (setq-local buffer-read-only t)))))
   (nil . ()))  ; ... (1)
  ```

  ```lisp
  ;;; /tmp/.dir-locals-2.el
  ;; ((nil . ()))  ; ... (2)
  ```

You probably suggest I remove one of these `(nil . ())`s to implement what I want.
Please don't do that, or you are simply avoiding my question.

Comment: How about simplifying the code/question by getting rid of the `eval` and just setting a variable instead?  Unless `eval` is crucial to the effect, but you haven't said that.

Comment: And while it might be ignoring the question, I can't fathom why you're even attempting to have a duplicate key in a single file like that.  I suggest you just read the code to answer your own question.

Comment: @phils: "*Unless eval is crucial to the effect, but you haven't said that.*" -- It really doesn't matter whether I said that. **The problem is right here; it won't disappear** -- even if I somehow get around this problem, won't other people encounter it?

Comment: @phils: Does <https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77973> help?

Comment: It does, yes.  I don't buy the "convenience" argument, but the `subdirs` part makes better sense of the question.  I'm surprised if duplicates are supported -- I would have expected only a single match for a given key to be processed -- but I agree that's a fair reason to be attempting it.  I would still simplify the question (and mention the `subdirs` case as a motivation).