# duplicate key in dir-locals file

Tags: directory-local-variables

Why does someone attempt to have a duplicate key in a single `.dir-locals.el`?

E.g.,

```lisp
((nil . (...))
 (nil . (...)))
```

Answer (score 3):

###### Convenient

We can add new per-directory variables anywhere; we don't need to locate where the same key is to set a new variable.

###### Efficient

For example,

```lisp
;;; /tmp/.dir-locals.el
((nil . ((my/name . shynur)))
 (nil . ((subdirs . nil)
         (my/name . none))))
```

So `my/name` will evaluate to `none` in `/tmp/file`;
in `/tmp/*/file` (or `/tmp/*/*/.../file`), it will evaluate to `shynur`.

You can implement this in other ways, but it must be messy.

Comment: Another possibility is that when `dir-locals` was added, it was "obvious" that there should never be a duplicate entry, but the check wasn't implemented: you might be hitting yet another undefined corner case. I'm not saying that's the case here, but it's good to always keep that possibility in mind. After all, Emacs is a 40-year-old piece of software that has had sometimes radical changes done to it: because of that, undefined behavior happens. It's good that you are exploring the dark recesses of Emacs' mind, but inevitably you'll run into such cases. Best thing to do is report it.

Comment: @NickD: "*Best thing to do is report it.*" -- Have added to my TODO list.